# String Pool exists in both young and old generation?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, heap-memory

From Java 7 interned Strings are no longer stored in permgen area. Rather they are stored in normal heap space which means they must undergo half GC and full GC. Now after half GC those interned String that survive must be transfered from young to old generation.

- Does that mean both young and old generation have this string poll?

Next lets say a string in interned. They I define an string literal with same content then in that case it has to point to same string innstance in the pool.

- So JVM has to serach for the String in both young and old generation
  and return reference to the approriate string instance. Is my
  thinking correct?

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the logical layout of the intern table with its physical arrangement in memory.  The intern table is just a hash table with chaining on collisions, logically (though not physically) similar to a HashMap.  When interning a string, the JVM hashes it, then looks in the appropriate bucket and either returns the string it finds or adds the new string to the bucket.

This is orthogonal to the garbage collector's management of generations.  Indeed, some collectors have more than two generations, and the [G1 (pronounced "garbage first") collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html) can use multiple regions for new or old objects.  When looking up a string, the JVM simply does a hash table lookup and follows some references/pointers, not a separate search in each generation/region as you suggest.